# Event when facebook login button is clicked

Tags: facebook

Is there any event that will fire when the Facebook Login button is clicked, but at no other time?

I would like the user to have the option to logout of my website, even while logged into Facebook.  I've set an 'AutoLogin' field in their user data.

When AutoLogin is False, and the Facebook Login button is clicked, I'd like the user to be logged back in again.

On a related note, I noticed when a user is logged into FB and clicks the Facebook Login button, a Facebook popup briefly appears.  Is there any way to avoid this brief popup?  And again, fire Javascipt that will take appropriate action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscribe to the login event.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response)
{
  console.log("login_event");
  console.log(response.status);
  console.log(response);
}
);
```

Comment: It's been awhile since I had this problem.  But still looks good.

Answer (score 3):

I've found this subscription to "login_event" only comes back after the auth process is well underway. So if you are trying to do something like show a loading modal with a "Waiting for Facebook" to show up on a slow 2G connection, then this doesn't really help you. And as mentioned by Dave, since Facebook is presenting it's button inside an iframe, you can't create an event listener for it.

However outside of the docs, you will find that Facebook is making extensive usage of the window messagebus to talk to it's iframes.

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(event){

    if(event.data.indexOf('_FB_') === 0){// these are facebook messages sent from it's iframes
        if(event.data.indexOf('proxy_ready') > 0){
            console.log('facebook ready');
        }

    }
}
```

It's helpful to console log all those messages with timestamps during your login process and figure out which ones to key off. Example:

```
2016-12-14 15:13:38.024 app.js:162 FB.init
2016-12-14 15:13:39.257 app.js:1366 _FB_f120116a3bc6178data&logged_in=false&xd_action=proxy_ready
2016-12-14 15:13:43.473 app.js:1366 _FB_f120116a3bc6178type=resize&cb=f291741ffe877f&width=300&height=39
2016-12-14 15:13:47.933 app.js:1366 _FB_f120116a3bc6178xd_action=plugin_ready&name=f66bbdc3fb088&cb=f291741ffe877f&domain=xxx.xxx&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fxxx.xxx%2Ff120116a3bc6178&relation=parent.parent
2016-12-14 15:13:47.934 app.js:1366 _FB_f120116a3bc6178type=resize&width=164&height=39&reposition=false&cb=f291741ffe877f&domain=xxx.xxx&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fxxx.xxx%2Ff120116a3bc6178&relation=parent.parent

clicked button IN FB popup here:
2016-12-14 15:14:24.571 app.js:1366 _FB_f120116a3bc6178type=resize&cb=f291741ffe877f&width=300&height=39
2016-12-14 15:14:29.053 app.js:1366 _FB_f120116a3bc6178xd_action=plugin_ready&name=f66bbdc3fb088&cb=f291741ffe877f&domain=xxx.xxx&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fxxx.xxx%2Ff120116a3bc6178&relation=parent.parent
2016-12-14 15:14:29.055 app.js:1366 _FB_f120116a3bc6178type=refreshLoginStatus&cb=f291741ffe877f&domain=xxx.xxx&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fxxx.xxx%2Ff120116a3bc6178&relation=parent.parent
2016-12-14 15:14:29.071 app.js:1366 _FB_f120116a3bc6178type=resize&width=164&height=39&reposition=false&cb=f291741ffe877f&domain=xxx.xxx&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fxxx.xxx%2Ff120116a3bc6178&relation=parent.parent
2016-12-14 15:14:30.188 app.js:1366 _FB_f120116a3bc6178cb=fbcdc5c882b3bc&domain=xxx.xxx&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fxxx.xxx%2Ff120116a3bc6178&relation=parent&code=AQCl6y6TvwzareonnVCLEFWVglwDApABbs3ATKnbd6iLSZbKZ...mwZDZD&expires_in=6331&base_domain=xxx.xxx&https=1
2016-12-14 15:14:30.193 app.js:171 login_event
2016-12-14 15:14:30.193 app.js:172 connected
2016-12-14 15:14:30.193 app.js:173 Object {authResponse: Object, status: "connected"}
2016-12-14 15:14:30.199 app.js:246 FB.getLoginStatus
2016-12-14 15:14:30.201 app.js:229 connected to FB app
2016-12-14 15:14:30.202 app.js:253 FB.api
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have seen this already but take a look at [these events](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) you can listen for.

Comment: Yes, but offhand I don't know whether any of those indicate the login button has just been clicked.  I don't even think I can assign an event on my own, since the button seems to be inside an iFrame.  It looks like I'm just going to have to change the design of the login process a little.

Comment: Couldn't you record the initial FB login status of the user, then listen for when the status changes, and take it from there? Maybe I'm not fully grasping your scenario

Comment: Technically, the user is logged into FB all the times in this scenario.  I just want the FB user to be able to log out of my site without logging out of FB.  So I am taking the FB userID and know what user it is, but not logging them in if their Autologon flag is set to false on my end.  Since they are already logged in to FB when clicking the button, I do not think there is a status change.  It appears they should not even have the FB button available if they are already logged in, so I decided to design the site a different way.  At this point it's just academic curiosity.